# Why isn't CompizConfigSettings Manager installed along side Unity?

Tags: unity, compiz, settings

If unity is shipped by default, and using CompizConfigSettings is recommended for configuration, shouldn't CompizConfigSettings Manager be installed along with it?

Comment: Acually you don't need ccsm these days to configure unity there are settings in gconf2 or the newer dconf-tools from the software centre. If you want a gui then you can use confity see http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/tag/confity/ for more details and how to install

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said by Mark Shuttleworth in the Bug Report that I filed asking the exact same thing,

> No, ccsm should not be installed by default. There are no options in Unity
>   through CCSM which are encouraged for
>   end-user experimentation. Anything
>   there can and will be altered and
>   removed. It's there to help us explore
>   options and gather testing feedback.
>   So please do not install ccsm by
>   default.

*(From the [Bug Report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/744267))*

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't have shipped it without a configuration tool, but that's not my call.

Comment: @astjohn Agreed. However, it's on track for 11.10.

Comment: Elsewhere -- in another bug report on Launchpad, I believe -- I recall Shuttleworth commenting that some of the options would cause Unity to crash. The overall impression is that Compiz config settings manager is, for the purposes of configuring Unity, only a kludge, to be replaced by a proper tool.

Comment: Unity crashes pretty frequently without changing ccsm setings ...

Answer (score 1):

As you have found, Canonical decided, either there wasnt enough space on the CD, or that they didnt consider this option as essential.  Can I suggest you make this suggestion via their [Mailing Lists](https://lists.ubuntu.com/#Development+Lists)?